# How to use a variable set in "view.phtml" in a controller file?

Tags: global-variable

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1.

The following contains a useful URL when run in "template/catalog/product/view.phtml".

```
$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

When I try to get the same URL by running the following from "Mage_Customer_AccountController". I don't get the same URL.

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Is there anyway I could save the URL value from "template/catalog/product/view.phtml" and be able to use that variable in "Mage_Customer_AccountController" methods ?

Don't hesitate to provide code snippets as I'm new in Magento.

Thanks

Comment: Which `view.phtml` file are you referring to? What's the difference between the URLs?

Comment: the `getCurrentUrl` method returns the URL you are on, the one you see in your browser. Since the `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file means your on a product (could be any url) and `Mage_Customer_AccountController` means your on the url `customer/....` these 2 won't return the same URL as they aren't the same page

Comment: I have couples of website pages that need customers to login. After beeing logged in, I'm trying to get customers back to the URL adress before loging success. That URL adress seems to be only visible from "template/catalog/product/view.phtml". But I need to use that URL adress from the file "Mage_Customer_AccountController". I could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code lines allowed me to set a variable from "theme_lpf/template/catalog/product/view.phtml"

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$session->setData("urlBeforeLoginSuccess", $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
```

and use it from a new module "ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/controllers/AccountController.php" as follows.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$urlBeforeLoginSuccess = $session->getData("urlBeforeLoginSuccess");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a referer URL.

When you create your login form, use this code to generate the URL (untested):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', array('referer' => Mage::helper('core/url')->urlEncode(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()) ?>">
[...]
```

This will result in:

```
[your-domain]/customer/account/loginPost/referer/[base64-encoded-current-domain]
```

As you are using the normal customer account controller, it should be enough to set the configuration value in the backend to enable this referer.

Also, from your question I assume that you are about to change the account controller file's contents - don't do this! Magento is a very flexible system where you actually never need to change core files. You can achieve everything you want by simply programming an extension.